# Powershell - Expand subArray and rename fields

Tags: powershell

I have a source array like this

```
$myArray = (
   @{ id = "1"; name = "first item"; 
       subArray = (
           @{ id = "A"; name = "first subitem" }, 
           @{ id = "B"; name = "second subitem" } ) 
   },
   @{ id = "2"; name = "second item"; 
       subArray = (
           @{ id = "C"; name = "third subitem" }, 
           @{ id = "D"; name = "fourth subitem" } ) 
   }
)
```

I need to extract the relations between the parent and child arrays like following:

```
source     target
-----------------
1           A
1           B
2           C
2           D
```

I have come up with a following code to achieve that

```
$myArray | ForEach-Object {
    $id = $_.id
    $_.subArray | ForEach-Object { 
        @{
            source = $id
            target = $_.id
        } 
    }
}
```

I wonder if there is some more straight forward solution.

Edit:

Based on Marsze answer - slightly modified solution

```
$myArray| ForEach-Object  
    {$a=$_; $a.subArray | Select-Object @{n="source";e={$a.id}},@{n="target";e={$_.id}}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks pretty straightforward to me. You could use `foreach` loops instead of the pipeline cmdlet, which is faster and has the advantage, that you can reference variables on each level directly.

Also I recommended converting to `PSCustomObject` for the proper output format:

```bsh
foreach ($a in $myArray) {
    foreach ($b in $a.subArray) {
        [PSCustomObject]@{source = $a.id; target = $b.id}
    }
}
```

Alternatively with `New-Object`:

```bsh
foreach ($a in $myArray) {
    foreach ($b in $a.subArray) {
        New-Object PSObject -Property @{source = $a.id; target = $b.id}
    }
}
```

Or the `Select-Object` version:

```bsh
foreach ($a in $myArray) {
    $a.subArray | select @{n="source";e={$a.id}},@{n="target";e={$_.id}}
}
```